# DynamoDB PHP SDK- fastest bulk import method?

Tags: php, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to bulk import ~ 110 million records into DynamoDB.

Using CFBatchRequest:

```
    $queue = new CFBatchRequest(800);
```

and then adding 800 put_item()'s to it only results in around 190 writes/second, and oddly results in cURL errors every so often.  It doesn't seem to matter what size instance I use.  And I've tried doing less or more than 800.

Doing singleton put_item() is incredibly slow.  And batch_write_item() has no retry feature, plus it's only limited to 25.

I read that EMR does not using any batching at all, and a search here shows some people having problems with it.

Is there a better way of approaching this?

Comment: this may help https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=333470

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you using the very, very latest version of the SDK? (1.5.11 at this moment)
2. Reducing the size of the request pool will reduce the chance of batching errors. If you're setting it to 800, you're almost certainly flooding cURL.
3. If that doesn't help, [PM](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/profile.jspa?userID=145599) me on the official AWS forums, referencing this SO thread, and we can chat about this some more.

Comment: Sent you a PM...sincerely appreciate your offer to help.